# If in category to be inside of a function

Tags: categories, functions, code

I have this code in WordPress **index.php** and I was wondering how can I transfer this in to a **functions.php** to be a part of a **function**?

```
<?php if (in_category('featured')) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">  <span  class="featured_icon">     
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/featured_icon.png" />  
</span></a>                     
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank You in advance for Your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the function to output the code somewhere:

```
function displayImage($currentPost) {

    // Show the featured icon only if current post is in "featured" category
    if ( in_category ( 'featured', $currentPost ) ) {

        $output = '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <span  class="featured_icon">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/featured_icon.png" />  
                            </span>
                      </a>';
    }

    else { $output = '' };
    return $output;

}
```

Then you can just pass the post id and echo the function.

Comment: Edited to make the code more readable. Hope you dont mind. :)

Comment: @AahanKrish Thank You :) Any idea how to place it inside this code to be a part of a function from pastie here: http://pastie.org/4276093 in between line 16 and 19? I really need help :)

Comment: @fdsa Thank You :) Any idea how to place it inside this code to be a part of a function from pastie here: http://pastie.org/4276093 in between line 16 and 19? I really need help :)

Comment: @jimilesku just place this function inside your functions.php and then somewhere you should have a `$display.= displayImage($post->ID)`